# Chatfuel Export

Tags: export, chatfuel

Has anyone found a way to export a project from Chatfuel into another account?

I know I can clone into my own account, that's not what I am trying to do. I am trying to avoid having to create the whole thing again.

I have built a project bot for a client and now need to put it in his account and link it to his Facebook page. The fact there is nothing obvious suggest this is a tool for hobbyists and personal bots, not something for developers with clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way to do it :)

1. Go to your **chatfuel dashboard** (your account).
2. Click on **your chatbot**.
3. On the left-side menu, click on **Configure**.
4. Scroll down a little bit, you will see a block named ADMINS. Click on **Invite Admins**
5. **Copy the link** you will see.
6. **Log out**.
7. **Log in with the other account** where you want to get your chatbot cloned to.
8. **Open the link** you have on your clipboard.
9. Go to your chatfuel dashboard. **You will now see the chatbot you wanted to clone**.

Finally, you could keep working on this chatbot (makes sense) or maybe just clone it and keep working on a copy of it, so you are the only admin of this one.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I had to work through this with the client because unless you have 2 accounts of course you cannot see the other side. It all works quite smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning is a way to make a copy of the bot in your own account.

What you want to do is add the client to the bot aswell. This can be done in the configure section of the bot. There you can get an "admin invite" link. If you send that link to the client, they can get their own ChatFuel dashboard with that bot in it, provided they are also logged into facebook.

Additionally, it allows them to remove you from the bot. This means you can also use this to transfer a bot from your account to someone else's account.